# Using the definite article with acronyms and initialisms with a number in front of it

Tags: articles, definite-articles, acronyms, initialisms

I understand that using a definite article with an initialism. For example WKC for World Kendo Championship needs "the" if it pronounces "double-U kay si." I want to know if "the" is still need if it accommodates with number in front of it as 18WKC "Eighteen WKC." My understanding is no definite article required. Am I right?

Comment: How common is it to call the 18th WKC just "18WKC"?

Comment: It's  quite often. Almost always it's called or referred as 18WKC (pronounced as eighteen bouble-u kay si not eighteenth). That's why I'd like to know if "the" is required or not. The 18WKC or just 18WKC.